# JavaScript and EditorFor for model in different contexts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, editorfor

How do you make javascript code /specifically jQuery/ to work with HTML code that gets generated via `EditorFor` and the corresponding editor template?

The thing is, we might have a model called `PostCode` (or `Zip`, doesn't really matter) and it would have a `PostCode.ascx` in the `EditorTemplates` folder and then render this partial via `EditorFor` in various parent views for "parent" models(they might be `Address`, `Company`, etc.)..

When we render it with `EditorFor` we make sure it will render the necessary prefix like `Address.PostCode.postname` so the binding will continue to work (when posted back to the controller action it will pick it up and set up correct navigation properties/references).

The problem is, the ID and name attributes change depending on where we render it. Somehow I need to render the adjusted JS in that case.

The only other option would be using `RenderPartial` which I had before and which does not alter the IDs or names for the tags but consequentally fails to work because it doesn't render prefixes in HTML and as such binding fails.

Hopefully you understand what I mean and someone already got this figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of different ids generated by editor templates based on the context could be solved by using CSS class selectors instead of id selectors.